# Deploying a Outlook 2007 Addin created from Visual Studio 2010 for All Users

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I'm trying to deploy a Outlook 2007 addin for all users in windows 7. I developed the addin using visual studio 2010 to simply to show a message box on load.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test addin");
        }
```

Since it is stated that creating a installer using Publish(ClickOnce) feature will not install the addin to all users, i tried creating an MSI setup project following the steps given in, 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx#Create

Since I'm targeting only Outlook 2007, I executed only the steps up to configuring the registry.

Once I created the setup and installed it (selecting Everyone), the addin does not run initially in outlook. when I checked it in Trust Center, I could see my addin listed in the Inactive Application Addins Section.

[image]
Once I checked in the system registry(using regedit), all the Registry Key are properly included under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` as well.

(When I install it Selecting Only me, the addin works fine.)

Can anyone please help me to get this working for all users.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a second part to the tutorial which shows how to handle trust as part of the installation. You can find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc616991%28office.12%29.aspx#VSTO3Solutions2_HandlingTrustasPartoftheInstallation).

Comment: Thanks, i did this part as well, but still no change. I even tried creating a separate console application to add the inclusion list entry as stated here, 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398239.aspx

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial for deploying an outlook add-in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136646(office.12).aspx