# Outlook 2010 COM Addin does not install for all users

Tags: c#, com, outlook, add-in, ribbon

I am trying to isntall an AddIn that I created using Visual Studio 2010 that adds a new ribbon button to Outlook 2010.

It all wokrs perfect untill it comes to deploying it to machines with multiple users. The Addin only installs for the currently logged in user.

What can i do to make it install for everyone? I have tried all the instructions/links from this post as well a other website: [Deploying a Outlook 2007 Addin created from Visual Studio 2010 for All Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713120/deploying-a-outlook-2007-addin-created-from-visual-studio-2010-for-all-users)

I tried to look into suggestions of changing registry from HKEY_CURRENT_USER to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE but there are no keys in Current_User in visual studio in my project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to install the AddIn? VS Setup Project, InstallShield, etc.?

Comment: Am using the .msi i got when building the project.

Comment: So you are using a [VS Setup Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes i am. Tried creating the Registry keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE but when i run the setup, the registry entries does not get populated.

Comment: What is the full registry path (*hive*) you are creating using your setup project?

Comment: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyCompany.Addin]
"Description"="My Outlook AddIn"
"FriendlyName"="My Outlook AddIn"
"LoadBehavior"=dword:00000003
"Manifest"="[ProgramFilesFolder]OutlookAddin\\Outlook\\OutlookAddIn2.vsto|vstolocal"

Comment: What is your host OS? Is it x86 or x64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting your registry keys into the wrong hive based upon your OS platform (*you are putting the keys into the x86 OS instead of x64 OS path*). The proper registry key for all users on an x64 machine is given below. Please update your installer appropriately.

#### All User Hive (x86 Office on x64 OS)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\[add-in ID]
```

Also [see related SO post discussing VSTO addins not appearing automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8606087/175679).

Comment: Thanks SilverNinja, but from this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/08/deploying-your-vsto-add-ins-to-all-users-saurabh-bhatia.aspx it says: A 64-bit version of Office 2010 on 64-bit OS will always load the add-ins under this key:

e.g. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\application name\Addins\add-in ID shall i still add t to Wow6432Node?

Comment: Speaking from previous experience - you **must use Wow6432Node** due to **Registry Reflection**. This article was written almost 3 years back when x86 was still commonly used. See [related forum post](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/installing-outlook-addin-users-129552.aspx). [Also from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64): *`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node` is the 32-bit equivalent of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software` (although 32-bit applications are not aware of this redirection).* Finally - [see another related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10734645/175679).

Comment: Thanks alot. Will give it a try and let you know how it goes.